Why won't react navigation work on a Modal in React Native?
Why am I unable to navigate to the DriverTipSlider Page in the Modal? it only works if I click on it, and then close the current modal, then it would navigate to that page. I want it to navigate when I already have the modal opened. I don't want to have to close it all the time. Here is the code:
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Modal, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
// import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

const MobileModal = ({ setSecondModalVisible, secondModalVisible, navigation }) => {
//   const navigation = useNavigation();

  const navigateToDriverTipSlider = () => {
    navigation.navigate('DriverTipSlider'); // Navigate to DriverTipSlider
  };

  return (
    <Modal
      visible={secondModalVisible}
      animationType="slide"
      transparent={false}
      onRequestClose={() => setSecondModalVisible(false)}
    >
      <View style={{ flex: 1, paddingTop: 100, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <View>
          <Text>MobileModal</Text>
        </View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={navigateToDriverTipSlider} style={{ flex: 1, paddingTop: 10 }}>
          <Text>Go to DriverTipSlider</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setSecondModalVisible(false)} style={{ flex: 1, paddingTop: 10 }}>
          <Text>Close</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </Modal>
  );
};

export default MobileModal;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});

